# Mysql_fetch_assoc not functioning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cannot, not matter what, figure out why I am getting this error in my code:

> mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$session_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$getall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='' . $dbuser_id . ''");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getall);

$fullnameDB         = $row['name'];
$emailDB            = $row['email'];
$usernameDB         = $row['username'];

$fullname           = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
$username           = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$email              = strip_tags($_POST['email']);


if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='' . $username . ''");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

    if ($count !=0) {

        echo 'That username is already taken!';

    } else {

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username=' . $username . ' WHERE id='' . $dbuser_id . ''");

        echo 'Your UN has been updated';

    }

}                        

?>
```

Comment: **warning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Because your quotes don't match? You open with a double quote and look to be trying to close with two apostraphes.

Comment: Please improve your title to match your question. And please post your **relevant** code here on SO.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @ImagineCustoms as I said, if you find it helpful, please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'"
```

not

```
"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='' . $username . ''"
```

But consider switching to parameterised statements with mysqli or pdo

Comment: you should be more specific, as that type of error occurs more than once in ImagineCustom's Code.

Comment: @think123 - when I answered, there was only one SQL statement in the code

Comment: yes that's true, then you should consider editing your answer for more up votes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refined version of your code:

```
<?php

$session_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$getall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" . $dbuser_id . "'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getall);

$fullnameDB         = $row['name'];
$emailDB            = $row['email'];
$usernameDB         = $row['username'];

$fullname           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
$username           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email              = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

    if ($count !=0) {

        echo 'That username is already taken!';

    } else {

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='" . $username . "' WHERE id='" . $dbuser_id . "'");

        echo 'Your UN has been updated';

    }

}                        

?>
```

What you did wrong was that in your query, you started it with double quotes (") but you tried to end it halfway through to concatenate your username with single quotes('), so it didn't work. I also helped sanitize your inputs, to make it less vulnerable (if not safe) to SQL injections.

**EDIT:** As other users have mentioned, seriously consider to switching to prepared statements.

Comment: Post answers here, not on pastebin

Comment: @ImagineCustoms then can you please mark as a correct answer? just click the white tick on the side.

Comment: why did someone downvote me? did I make a mistake?

Comment: @John You're knocking him for not doing extra work for the OP?

Comment: Note that this is still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I tried to change as little as possible.

Comment: I edited it anyway. And someone downvoted me again. What is it I did? I am striving to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code, and it is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Use this code:

```
<?php
try {
    $session_id = session_id();
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'any_user_other_than_root', 'secure_password', 'database');
    if(!$conn) throw new Exception('Could not connect to the database.');
    $dbuser_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbuser_id);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$dbuser_id'";
    $getall = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!$getall) throw new Exception('Database query failed!');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getall);
    $fullname_db = $row['name'];
    $email_db = $row['email'];
    $username_db = $row['username'];
    $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $namecheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if(!$namecheck) throw new Exception('Name check failed!');
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($namecheck);
        if($count > 0) {
            echo 'That username is already taken!';
        } else {
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET username='$username' WHERE id='$dbuser_id'");
            if(!$result) throw new Exception('Could not update your UN.');
            echo 'Your UN has been updated';
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that this is _still_ vulnerable to SQL injection attacks under certain circumstances, and you really should be using prepared statements.

Comment: you should try and keep your code as similar to ImagineCustom's original code as possible, because it will help ImagineCustom understand the code better, if you keep it in a format ImagineCustom understands.

Comment: @ think123 I kept it as close as I could, while making it better.    
                                                             
    @Lusitanian - I mean to learn prepared statements, and OOP in general sometime soon. :-)