# Why Is This Code Producing A Fail?

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_GET['email']) && !isset($_GET['key'])) {

        echo 'NOT ALLOWED TO ACCESS PAGE';

    }

    if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['key'])) {

        $email      = $_GET['email'];
        $regKey     = $_GET['key'];

        $query      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `regRandom`='$regKey'");

        if ($query == $regKey) {

            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `activated`=1 WHERE `email`='$email'");

            if (mysql_query("SELECT activated FROM users WHERE activated='1'")) {

                echo file_get_contents("http://TheMegaHouse.com/pageContent/head.php");

                echo file_get_contents("http://TheMegaHouse.com/pageContent/notLoggedIn/topNavBar.php");

                echo file_get_contents("http://TheMegaHouse.com/pageContent/header.php");

                echo 'PASSED';

                footer();

            } else {

                activationFail();
            }

        } else if ($regKey !== $query) {

            echo 'FAIL';
        }


    }


?>
```

The thing is that in my database, the value that is in the `regRandom` column is in fact equal to the value in the `key` variable in the url but for some reason it is echoing out "FAIL" instead of "PASSED".

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, a better way of doing what I want to do or any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest not demanding that people fix it - we all have day jobs :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish If you try to edit it, you'll see the preview looks readable but for some reason the final, submitted version is not. I guess this is a bug.

Comment: @DougT looks reasonable now - maybe my browser - will edit my comment

Comment: Looks like you ignored all the advice in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118206/46675. Copy/paste/crowdsource coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always read manual first:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

This line of code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `regRandom`='$regKey'");
```

Is returning you resource, instead of variable you are lookng for.

Small fix for you:

```
list($regRandom) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT regRandom  FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `regRandom`='$regKey'"));
if ($regRandom == $regKey) {
  // magic
```

And another two things:

- `mysql_*` functions are deprecated
- i strongly recommend you to read about SQL Injections.

Comment: Thank You Peter for your help, everything seems to be working fine now :)

I will get rid of the mysql function also

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions but switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

However, the problem you are having is that you are comparing a resource to a sent-in variable.

My guess is that `$regKey` is an integer and `$query` is the result of a mysql query. You need to fetch a row from the result-set and compare a specific value from that row to your `$regKey`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if Im wrong, but $query results is a resource? You haven't done anything with it.

I would suggest just doing a simple mysql_num_rows() check like this:

```
$query      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `regRandom`='$regKey'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
```

Its pointless to check again because you are already checking in the SQL query :) So simply check the number of rows returned. 0 = not found, 1+ = results :)